# show data in datetime when using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Now I have a json like this :

`[{"trackId":2,"userName":"sales","location":"klb","dateTime":{"date":"2014-11-22 21:36:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"remarks":"test4321","createBy":"sales","createDate":"12 November, 2014","status":"11","updateBy":"sales","updateDate":{"date":"2014-11-12 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"parkingNum":"","statusDesc":null}]`

Anyone can help me how I can get **date value** inside the **dateTime** ?Below is my code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../cdc/load/jsonTrack.php',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, status) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        var trackId = (val.trackId);
                        var userName = (val.userName);
                        var location = (val.location);
                        var dateTime = (val.dateTime);
});
}
});
```

Please someone help me.Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code use `val.dateTime.date` as show below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../cdc/load/jsonTrack.php',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                var trackId = (val.trackId);
                var userName = (val.userName);
                var location = (val.location);
                var dateTime = (val.dateTime);
                console.log(val.dateTime.date);
                var date = val.dateTime.date;
            });
        }
});
```